# drupal what if we have designed a content type with existing fields

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views, drupal-modules

i have small problem....
i have one content type say cars with various fields, say more than 30 , user can create the content types...
now i would like to show only few fields in different phases,is there any possibility to do that.
more explantaion:-
user may enter the car model and car details in the first page and upload images in second page.(say a popup in the block)
is this is possible ?
i m newbie to drupal, i would like to do this kind of data updation,

i though with designing a one more content type with the existing fields, can any one explain this issue...
what if i design a content type car1 with same fields say(file uplaod) in car content type.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's a tutorial on how to create multistep forms using CCK's field group functionality](http://www.davidnewkerk.com/book/106). It's a little complicated, but it works.

Comment: it works when i go through all the steps sequentially, but in my case it dosen't
 happen that way.